# All browsers load local CSS but not applying it

Tags: google-chrome, browser, localhost, css, django

All browsers in my computer doesn't apply local CSS but it loads it if it was from website.

Here as you see it loads CSS, but does not apply it:
[image: Here as you see it loads CSS but not applied]

But if I changed one character at least, then it is applied:
[image: There as you ca see it is now applied]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was **operating system fault**.

**To take over this choose one of the solutions down there**

- Just uplaod CSS on an website and use it.
- Reinstall operating system.